# Firestore arrayunion provides any callback?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxtjs

Hi I am building some kind of voting system and I have like to prevent the same user from voting in the same post.

```
  let db = firebase.firestore();
  var postRef = db.collection("posts").doc(this.pid);
  postRef.update({
    votes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
  });
  var userRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.userId);
  userRef.update({
    votes: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.pid)
  });
  //run this line if pid is added
  this.votes = this.votes + 1;
```

I have like to increase the vote only if pid is added to the votes array.  I wonder if arrayUnion is able to provide some kind of feedback on this or anyway I can do that.

You can look at [this post](https://gamecrawl.com/play/x_QjmG26SS0) and you can see that the same person can vote multiple times on the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, by design `increment` and `arrayUnion` don't provide any callback.

In order to implement your requirement, you need a *transaction* (used by both `increment` and `arrayUnion` under the hood):

```js
const postRef = db.collection("posts").doc(this.pid);
const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(this.userId);

db.runTransaction(async (t) => {
    const post = await t.get(postRef);
    const user = await t.get(userRef);

    if (!user.get('votes').includes(this.pid)) {
        t.update(postRef, {votes: post.get('votes') + 1});
        t.update(userRef, {votes: [...user.get('votes'), this.pid]});
    }
});
```

- https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Transaction
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions